# Remove trailing letters at the end of string

Tags: string, bash

I have some strings like below:

````
ffffffffcfdeee^dddcdeffffffffdddcecffffc^cbcb^cb`cdaba`eeeeeefeba[NNZZcccYccaccBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB

eedeedffcc^bb^bccccbadddba^cc^e`eeedddda`deca_^^\```a```^b^`I^aa^bb^`_b\a^b```Y_\`b^`aba`cM[SS\ZY^BBB
````

Each string may (or may not) end with a stretch of trailing `B` of varied length.
I'm just wondering if we can simply use Bash code to remove the `B` stretch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like

```
sed 's/\(.\)B*$/\1/' file
```

Input

```
aaa BBBBB
aaa BBBBB cccc
aaa bbb ccc BBBBBBB
```

Output

```
aaa
aaa BBBBB cccc
aaa bbb ccc
```

Answer (score 3):

just with bash

```
shopt -s extglob
str="a.zxn;lqwyerpyqgha;lsdnBBBBB"
str=${str%%+(B)}
echo $str   # ==> a.zxn;lqwyerpyqgha;lsdn
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed 's/B*$//' file
```